# Importing async functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm a beginner with Node and Javascript and Puppeteer. Given the following code, in which I'm simply trying to use one function from a different file:

```js
const waitForFrame = require ("../../lib/frames");
const screenshotFolder = 'test/screenshots';

module.exports = async(page) => {

    try {
      const iframe = await waitForFrame(page);
      await iframe.waitForSelector('.competition-response__copy');
      await page.waitForSelector({
        visible: '.competition-response__copy'
      });

      const confirmationMessageText = await frame.$eval('.competition-response__copy > p', e => e.textContent);
      return confirmationMessageText;

    } catch (err) {
      await page.screenshot({
        path: screenshotFolder + '/saveYourEntryButton.png',
        fullPage: true
      });
    }
```

And a helper file called:

```js
module.exports = async function waitForFrame(page) { export async 
function waitForFrame(page) {
  let fulfill;
  const promise = new Promise(x => fulfill = x);
  checkFrame();
  return promise;

  function checkFrame() {
    const frame = page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'iframe');
    if (frame) {
      fulfill(frame)
    } else
      page.once('frameattached', checkFrame);
  }
};
```

And my package json is as follows:

```js
"engines": {
  "node": ">=6"
},
"dependencies": {
  "chai": "^4.1.2",
  "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
  "lodash": "^4.17.10",
  "mocha": "^5.2.0",
  "puppeteer": "^1.6.2",
  "yargs": "^12.0.1",
  "express": "^4.16.4",
  "supertest": "^3.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "chai": "^4.2.0",
  "chai-dom": "^1.8.1",
  "mocha": "^5.2.0",
  "js-comments": "^0.5.4",
  "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
  "express": "^4.16.4",
  "supertest": "^3.3.0",
}
}
```

I am receving an error as follows:

```js
import {waitForFrame} from "../../lib/frames";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
```

I'm sure this has a beginners error but grateful for a quick pointer.  I'm aware there are a number of different methods to import depending on which standards of Javascript you are adhering too.

Thanks

Comment: Node.js support for ES6 modules is still experimental. https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use `import` as native, but this's [no still supported on ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import), the problem is not related with async functions but import as an unexpected token, you have some alternatives:

1. Don't use `import` or`export` and instead use:

   const waitForFrame = require("../../lib/frames");

This works very well and is supported in Node 6.

2. Migrate to Node 10, in that [version is supported](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) and you can use it.
3. Use a Compiler, like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) or any other that works for you, this involve include more dependencies, but then you can use modern APIs on oldest Node versions.

All depends on what you prefer.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thank you that does help my understanding.  However, in order to use the function in the frames.js script, I must still export the function from that file right? Using the code with the import you suggest in point 1 results in: export async function waitForFrame(page) {
 ^^^^^ ....SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Comment: ah, I think I have it cracked and have updated original. Thank you!